# Multiple SUM 's in one statement with IN

Tags: sql

This should hopefully be an easy solution but I can't think of how to do it.  I simply want to have a sql statement to get the sums of several items within one statement.

```
Column names:
LIPQOH
LBLITM
```

Statement I tried:

```
SELECT SUM(LIPQOH) as x, IBLITM 
FROM CPJDDTA81.F4101JD 
WHERE IBLITM IN('123456','1254484')
```

This statement returns the TOTAL sum of all the part numbers within the IN statement but I want it to return a sum for each instead.  I hope this makes sense and someone can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group on the `IBLITM` field:

```
SELECT SUM(LIPQOH) as x, IBLITM 
FROM CPJDDTA81.F4101JD 
WHERE IBLITM IN('123456','1254484')
GROUP BY IBLITM
```

Comment: Oh now I feel like an idiot haha :) Thank you for the speedy response!  It was so quick that I can't accept it as the correct answer right now..

Answer (score 3):

You should use a "`GROUP BY`":

```
SELECT SUM(LIPQOH) as x, IBLITM 
FROM CPJDDTA81.F4101JD 
WHERE IBLITM IN('123456','1254484') 
GROUP BY IBLITM
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you're looking for the [`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause:

```
SELECT SUM(LIPQOH) as x, IBLITM 
FROM CPJDDTA81.F4101JD 
WHERE IBLITM IN('123456','1254484')
GROUP BY IBLITM
```